# excel spreadsheet links to pics

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an excel spreadsheet that I need to attach pics to and send it to a customer but the pics are located on my computer and will not be on their computer is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you just zip the pics and the Excel Sheet together and send a zip?  If that is not an option you would need to go to Insert --> Picture and insert each picture one by one

Comment: can I zip the pics and insert without having to insert each pic one by one?

Comment: Theoretically that should work.  If you go to the Insert Tab of Excel, and within the Text Heading click on Object.  From the pop-up window that will display click the second tab titled Create from file.  Browse to the location of your zip file, then click ok.  The zip should now be embedded in your worksheet.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I posted it as answer.

Comment: it did not work it only allows one pic at a time

Comment: And it's a hack...  See CharlieRB post for a real answer

Comment: how do i get to CharlieRB post? i looked but didnt see anything about this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use the insert function (`Insert tab > Illustrations group > Picture`) to add the pictures into the spreadsheet (not link them). The downside is this can cause the file to be very large as this actually includes the picture files in the Excel file.

[image]
[source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-pictures-3c51edf4-22e1-460a-b372-9329a8724344)

Alternately, you can upload the pictures to a file sharing site and then place a hyperlink to each image in the Excel sheet. The user will then click the link to view the picture.